# Using pointers and union

Tags: c++, c

I've just started to learn C. I think I did something wrong with the pointer here or didn't understand the meaning of it. Look this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Uniao{
int i;
float f;
char c[4];
};
void test(union Uniao *uniao);
int main(){
union Uniao uniao;
printf("uniao.i: %x\n"
    "uniao.f: %x\n"
    "uniao.c: %x\n",
    &uniao.i, &uniao.f,&uniao.c);
test(&uniao);
}
void test(union Uniao *uniao){
printf("uniao.i: %x\n"
    "uniao.f: %x\n"
    "uniao.c: %x\n",
    uniao->i, uniao->f,uniao->c);
}
```

As I understood, a pointer points to the memory location of the original variable. So the output using the pointer should be the same of the output using the original variable. But my output is something like:

```
uniao.i: bfeac1dc
uniao.f: bfeac1dc
uniao.c: bfeac1dc
uniao.i: b77abff4
uniao.f: 80000000
uniao.c: beef57fe
```

Is there something wrong with my pointer or I misunderstood it?

Comment: Please explain your intentions, try to describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Your union is uninitialised

Comment: @mathematician1975 I think it doesn't matter, because the memory is already allocated and I just want it's position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you're printing the address of each member of the union. Being members of a union, they all have the same address. Inside of the function, you're printing the **values** of the members. (Which, having different types, will produce odd results here.) Adding `&` before each unaio in the second printf call will give you the results you expect.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I though I needed to use * to make the pointer print the value, but I just tested what you said and it worked. I will accept your answer in 3min

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is formatting the **memory addresses** of the union members, whereas `test()` is formatting the **values** of the members instead.

Answer (score 0):

IN your first printf statement in main you use '&' that returns the address of each member (all should be same for a union), but in 'Test' function you pass the values of each union member anot the addresses - i.e. no '&'. This is why you get different output values.

Comment: yeah,  I though I needed to use * to make the pointer print the value, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turn warnings on on your compiler, so that it tells you what it thinks of your code. It should find about six or so bad bugs.

Comment: You're right. As it shows some warnings I thought they were already on.